# Dragging coordinates with CGPoint

Tags: ios, drag, gesture, cgrect, cgpoint

I want to get the coordinates from the user's finger while dragging. I tried this code, but it says the coordinates are always {0, 0},
What's wrong?

```
- (IBAction)Drag{
UIPanGestureRecognizer *Recognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dragged)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:Recognizer];
}
-(void) dragged{
UITouch *touch ;
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint (location));
}
```

I also tried `NSLog(@"%.2f %.2f" location.x, location.y);` and got the same.
Thanks

Comment: Works, thank u so much!

Answer (score 0):

It's quite normal, you're using `touch` without having ever assigned a value to it.

The action for a gesture recognizer takes a parameter, which is the recognizer itself, which in turn has a `locationInView:` method, so you should use that. Also, you need to check the state of the recognizer. Finally, you probably don't want to add the gesture recognizer when you need it, just add it from the start.

```
// probably in your viewDidLoad
UIPanGestureRecognizer *Recognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                       action:@selector(panGestureRecognizerAction:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:Recognizer];

- (void)panGestureRecognizerAction:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan ||
        recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        CGPoint location = [recognizer.state locationInView:touch.view];
        NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint (location));
    }
}
```